# What is the difference in the meaning between 'it will end soon" and "it will be ending soon"?

Tags: difference, future-continuous, future

Is there a difference in the meaning  between "it will end soon" and "it will be ending soon"?. I don't see one may be the second one indicates that it has been planned before.

> My vacation will be ending soon.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. There is no difference in meaning, but the second is more likely to be used of a situation with a predictable end time.